# morris pie chart with a larger data

Tags: javascript, jquery, morris.js

I need to know how can with jquery maybe show a better pie chart with morris.js...with jquery flot the library I can hide the result with per example less than 100 coincidences but with morris I don't know how?

Here the capture:

[image: morris with a larger data]

and I want to show it like this one:

[image: second capture]

here is the jquery i use:

```
<script type='text/javascript' charset='utf-8'> 
$(function () {
    var pie = {
        element: 'pie',
        hideHover: 'auto',
        resize: true,
        data: <?php include('graficas6.php'); ?>,
  colors: [
    '#1424b8',
    '#0aa623',
    '#940f3f',
    '#148585',
    '#098215',
    '#b86c14',
    '#b83214'
  ],
        formatter: function (y) {
            return y + " "
        }
    }
    donut1 = Morris.Donut(pie)
}); 
</script>
```

Comment: Hide it in `graficas6.php`

Comment: @mainstreetmark but doing that all results when someone start will be hiding...so I need that the library maybe can hide automatically when see a larger data...

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest if you have the large data then you should use pagination ,so that data will be shown on each of the different pages.

There are many benefits if you look into these website.

https://demo.aheadmetrics.com/#UIJGJX6MIQ

I am currently making my ecommerce sales report . Once it gets love i will put that link over here